# How to get Akka actor by name as an ActorRef?

Tags: scala, akka

In Akka I can create an actor as follows.

```
Akka.system(app).actorOf(Props(classOf[UnzipActor]), name="somename")
```

Then I am in a different class, how can I get this actor?

I can get an `ActorSelection`

```
lazy val unzip: ActorSelection =
  Akka.system.actorSelection("user/" + "somename")
```

However, a `ActorSelection` is not what I want; I want an `ActorRef`. How can I get a `ActorRef`?

I want to have an `ActorRef` since I wish to schedule a call to an `ActorRef` using the scheduler.

```
Akka.system(app).scheduler.schedule(
  5 seconds, 60 seconds, mustBeActorRef, MessageCaseClass())
```

Comment: Why you need actor ref, you can send message to actorseletion. However if, you are looking for a child actor within the parent context, you can use getContext().child("somename")

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the method `resolveOne` on an ActorSelection to get an ActorRef asynchronously.

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
Akka.system.actorSelection("user/" + "somename").resolveOne().onComplete {
  case Success(actorRef) => // logic with the actorRef
  case Failure(ex) => Logger.warn("user/" + "somename" + " does not exist")
}
```

ref : http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.6/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection

Comment: How can we do the same in java?

Answer (score 7):

[Looking up Actors by Concrete Path](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html):

> To acquire an `ActorRef` that is bound to the life-cycle of a specific actor you need to send a message, such as the built-in [`Identify`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/#akka.actor.Identify) message, to the actor and use the `sender()` reference of a reply from the actor.

But for the case you're describing, it might be more appropriate to use the scheduler to send a message to an `ActorRef` you already have (like `self` or a new temporary actor), and react to that message by sending a `MessageCaseClass` to `actorSelection("user/somename")`.

Comment: see also here http://letitcrash.com/post/55504766698/2-2-spotlight-actorselection-watch-and-identify